# When using Docker Containers, where are shared Python libraries stored?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

In an environment where Docker Containers are used for each application, where are Python's shared libraries stored? Are they stored separately within each Docker Container, or shared by the host O/S?

Additionally I'm wondering if it would be best practice to use a virtual environment regardless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like everything else in a Docker Container, your libraries are inside the container. Unless you mount a host volume, or a volume from another container of course. On the plus side, though, they're copy-on-write, so if you're not making changes to the libraries in your container (why would you do that anyway?) then you can have 100 running containers from the same image and they don't require any extra disk space.

*Some* people advocate for using a virtualenv within the container - there are pros and cons to the approach, and I don't think there's a one-sized-fits-all answer, though I would lean for not having a virtualenv.